# Loss Function on Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and currently i am struggling with Tensorboard. I want to display loss function on tensorboard but all i am getting is a blank tensorboard. Event file is created and i am also able to open tensorboard. Below is my code, any help is highly appreciated.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function


import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

I_TRAIN = "D:/./iris_training.csv"
I_TEST = "D:/./iristest.csv"

sess = tf.Session()
train_data = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(filename=I_TRAIN,
                                target_dtype=np.int,features_dtype=np.float32)

test_data = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(filename=I_TEST,
                                    target_dtype=np.int,features_dtype=np.float32)

explainer = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=4)]

z = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=explainer,hidden_units=[5, 10, 5],
                                   n_classes=3,model_dir="/tmp/iris_neural2")

z.fit(x=train_data.data,y=train_data.target,steps=5000)
accuracy = z.evaluate(x=test_data.data,y=test_data.target)["accuracy"]
#tf.summary.scalar('accuracy',accuracy)
loss = z.evaluate(x=test_data.data,y=test_data.target)["loss"]
tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
#merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('D:/irs_py',sess.graph)


print("\nThe accuracy of the model is ", accuracy)
print ("\nThe loss of the model is ",loss)
```

[Tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MARTo.png)

Code output:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 85000: accuracy = 0.966667, global_step = 85000, loss = 0.265843

The accuracy of the model is  0.966667

The loss of the model is  0.265843
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it goes:

Say loss and accuracy are two graphs that you want to obtain:

```
#Model network code

loss = z.evaluate(x=test_data.data,y=test_data.target)["loss"]
accuracy = z.evaluate(x=test_data.data,y=test_data.target)["accuracy"]

# Add summary scalar node
acc_summ = tf.summary.scalar('accuracy',accuracy)
loss_summ = tf.summary.scalar('accuracy',loss)

#Collect all summaries
merged_summary = tf.summary.merge([acc_summ, loss_summ])]
```

Let's see the code for running the session and writing the graphs to file:

```
summ_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(dir_path)

# session run (To be put inside batch-loop to log loss for each batch)
summary = session.run([merged_summary], feed_dict='your input')
summ_writer.add_summary(summary, global_step)

# Finally close the writer
summ_writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for replying, i took help from "Hands on ML with scikitlearn and tensorflow" as well as stackoverflow and finally i am able to complete what i intended. In case anybody is interested here is the link to the solution:
https://github.com/nish112/Using-Tendorflow-on-iris-dataset/blob/master/up_git_iris_tens.ipynb